# Can not find a way to check or uncheck checkbox in my view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view ,which I throw to another view ,In my partial view there is a `checkbox` which is **checked by default** I want to change its current (checked/unchecked) option from main view. Here is my **partial view** code:

```
<td class="sevenCol" name="sevenCol">
     <input type="checkbox" checked/>
</td>
```

Below shows partial view content:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var mobnum = $("#mobNo").val();
    var message = $("#txtMessage").val();
    alert(mobnum);
    $.ajax({
        url: "SmsSendFromOneToOne",
        type: "POST",
        data: { contactList: mobnum, message: message },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#gridGenerate").html(data);
           }
    });
});
```

Below verifies `checkbox` is **checked** or **unchecked** but it always returns `true` so how can I fix this?

```
$("#sendbtn").click(function () {![enter image description here][1]
    var maskId = $("#MASKLIST").val();
    var campaignName = $("#campaignName").val();

    var dataArray = {};
    $(".loadingmessage").show();
    $("#gridGenerate tr").each(function (iii, val) {
        var trId = $(this).attr("id");
        var isChecked = $('td[name=sevenCol]').find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked');
        //alert(isChecked);
        if (isChecked) {
            dataArray[iii] = {              
                'mobile': $(this).find(".secondCol").text(),
                'message': $(this).find(".thirdCol").text(),
                'type': $(this).find(".fifthCol").text()
            };
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SmsSendFromOneToOne(string contactList, string message)
{
    IList<GridPanel> cellInfoForForm1 =    _smsService.GetForm1ForViewing(contactList, message);
                return PartialView("partialGridPanel", cellInfoForForm1);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: add something you can select on,  a class or an id then follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery

Comment: i have selected a name property but when i change it's current(checked /unchecked) option it did not find the change

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally got my answer ,As i am binding a partial view and checkbox exits in it so i have to use jquery .live( events, data, handler(eventObject) )to solve the issue ..

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );
```

Again thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

it is a lot simpler if you put the selector directly on the field.  try adding a class to your checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="mobileCheck" checked/>
```

then in your script you can replace

```
var isChecked = $('td[name=sevenCol]').find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked');
```

with

```
var isChecked = $('.mobileCheck').is(':checked');
```

Comment: I tried this one but does not work .. actually checkbox come from another partial view so if we change it to main view it does not work 
so do i need to write java script code to that partial view ?

Comment: what are you trying to do?  this just checks if the check box is checked or not.  if you want to actually check the check box look at the link I posted in my comment earlier